# probability that the vertex set {1,...,k} is component of random graph

Tags: graphs, probability-theory, random-graphs

Consider a graph with vertices 1,...,n and suppose that each of the $\binom{n}{2}$pairs of vertices is, independently, an edge of this graph with probability *p*.Let $P_n$ denote the probability that this graph is connected.

(a)I want to derive an expression that involves $P_k$ for the probability that the vertex set {1,...,k} is a component of this graph.

(b) I want to derive the probability that vertex 1 is a member of a component of size k.

(c)I want to express $P_n$ in terms of $P_k$, k=1,...,n-1.

(d)Using the recursion of part (c) to find $P_6$

**Answer**

I know the probability that random graph is connected $\sim$ $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2n}}$ for large n

I also know the expected value of the number of components in the random graph

$E[C]=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k}\frac{(k-1)!}{n^k}$

How to use this corollary and equation of the number of components in the random graph to answer this question?
Your hints are needed.

Comment: In (a), what do you mean by "is a component of this graph"?

Comment: A graph is said to consist of r components if its vertices can be partitioned into  r subsets so that each subset is connected and, in addition, there are no edges between vertices in different subsets.

Comment: That doesn't directly answer my question, but I guess you want that $\{1,\dots,k\}$ is a connected component and is disconnected from the rest of the graph. OK, this is just $P_k$ times the probability that none of the vertices $\{k+1,\dots,n\}$ are connected to any of the vertices $\{1,\dots,k\}$ because the edges are independent.

Comment: I want expression for $P_n$ which involves $P_k$ indicating the probability that the vertex set {1,...,k} is the component of this graph